# log is not accessible in normal groovy file of grails3

Tags: grails, grails-3.0, grails-3.1

Migrated grails2 to grails3. 
In grails2 i used lots of 
`log.info,log.debug` 
statements in side 
 `src/main/groovy` files. 
but in grails-3 by default 
 `log` is not injected. 
it's giving error like `No such property: log for class`

Comment: Annotate the class with `@Slf4j`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a planned change. You can use `@groovy.util.logging.Commons` annotations on your non-grails classes to have `log` available. Also other like `@Log4j`, `@Slf4j` are available, depending on your logging library.

There is one more difference which is important - those annotations will add `log` as private property and classes which will inherit from them, will also need to be annotated to use logging. Alternative is to manually define protected logger on your class.